# Modification to Websphere Application server Admin Console URL

Tags: websphere

One of our app team has completed WAS server base installation. After the installation is complete he requires two things.

1. WebSphere admins to be able to access the WebSphere admin console via a URL
2. Users to be able to access the WAS Portal

To connect to the URL’s, they first connect to VPN and use the browser from base machine directly.By default we are seeing these urls.

Admin URL: https://hostnane.ibm.com:9043/ibm/console/logon.jsp
User URL https://hostname.ibm.com ( this one is hypothetical for now)

Application team wants to convert ibm.com to mycompany.com.

Can someone advise how can we change ?

Answer (score 0):

Please do the next step by step:

**1. How to change hostname on WebSphere Application Server**

If you are moving your IBM WebSphere Application Server configuration or migrating your environment, you might have to change host names or migrate profiles from one machine to another.

For example, the old hostname is example.com, we want to change to `was-tpx04.hq.com`

If the host name of a server or its ports is incorrect, then you might experience problems such as errors when you attempt to stop a server.

First, correct the host name for an application server using the wsadmin.sh scripting tool and command line tools.

```
was-tpx04:/u01/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin # ./wsadmin.sh -conntype NONE -lang jython
```

WASX7357I: By request, this scripting client is not connected to any server process. Certain configuration and application operations will be available in local mode.
WASX7031I: For help, enter: "print Help.help()"

```
wsadmin>AdminConfig.list('ServerIndex')
'(cells/exampleNode01Cell/nodes/exampleNode01|serverindex.xml#ServerIndex_1)'
                
wsadmin>AdminConfig.modify('(cells/exampleNode01Cell/nodes/exampleNode01|serverindex.xml#ServerIndex_1)',  "[[hostName was-tpx04.hq.com]]")
''
                
wsadmin>AdminConfig.show('(cells/exampleNode01Cell/nodes/exampleNode01|serverindex.xml#ServerIndex_1)',  'hostName')
'[hostName was-tpx04.hq.com]'
                
wsadmin>AdminConfig.save()
''
                
wsadmin>exit
                
was-tpx04:/u01/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin # ./stopServer.sh server1 -profileName AppSrv01
```

ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file
/u01/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/server1/stopServer.log
ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the AppSrv01 profile
ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: server1
ADMU3201I: Server stop request issued. Waiting for stop status.
ADMU4000I: Server server1 stop completed.

```
was-tpx04:/u01/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin # ./startServer.sh server1 -profileName AppSrv01
```

ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file
/u01/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/server1/startServer.log
ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the AppSrv01 profile
ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: server1
ADMU3200I: Server launched. Waiting for initialization status.
ADMU3000I: Server server1 open for e-business; process id is 52604
was-tpx04:/u01/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin #

Now, the hostname looks as follows:

**2. Second, you need to correct the host names for the ports that an
application server opens.**

For the application server, `select Servers > Application servers > application server > Ports.`

Select a port whose host name needs changing.

Change the host name in the Host field; Click OK. Change the host name is `was-tpx04.hq.com`

Continue selecting ports and changing host names until you correct each of the host names for the server ports.

Save the changes to the master configuration.

Restart the server.